# Storing constant DB records in code - is it bad practice?

Tags: c#, database, orm

I have the database (Oracle) with some static tables. I.e. values in these tables are read-only.  These tables have a structure like this:

```
FOOD_TYPE_ID                         FOOD_TYPE_NAME 
------------------------------------ ---------------
E34FD113-D793-4EA0-A0D2-6F379D1AAC00 APPLE
30939FE7-3B8E-4857-A6F8-BBCC37CF293C PEAR
25B474B4-264D-45D7-9873-F0E73484BA65 GRAPE
35B00E15-8B5D-4519-ADAC-AC4325E9DE7A MEAT
```

And in the other tables there is foreign key on FOOD_TYPE_ID.

In my application (C#) I have an ORM (DbLinq). And sometimes I have to write something like:

```
if (OrderedFood.FoodType.Name == "APPLE") ...
```

It's not very convenient, though, because in this case I always need to keep in mind the exact names stored in FOOD table. (In real case, these names are much longer)

I'm thinking of creating a class with a bunch of strings like:

```
public static class FoodTypes
{
public const string APPLE = "E34FD113-D793-4EA0-A0D2-6F379D1AAC00";
public const string PEAR = "E34FD113-D793-4EA0-A0D2-6F379D1AAC00";
public const string GRAPE= "25B474B4-264D-45D7-9873-F0E73484BA65";
public const string MEAT= "35B00E15-8B5D-4519-ADAC-AC4325E9DE7A";
...
}
```

So I would be able to use this class like this:

```
if (OrderedFood.FoodType.ID == FoodTypes.APPLE) ...
```

In this case I will always know, what FOOD types I have (and Visual Studio's IntelliSense will know it, too).
I know that in this case I duplicate DB values in my code, which is clearly not the best practice. But, is it very bad to do this?

And maybe there is the other way to refer to the DB values in the code?

Comment: There is.  `OrderedFood.FoodType.Name` is the right way to do it.  Why clutter your code with meaningless ids?

Answer (score 0):

Better to do public library Food.dll in wich declare all you need as enum(s) and add reference to your project.

```
public enum FoodTypes
{
    APPLE,
    PEAR,
    GRAPE,
    MEAT,
    ...
}
```

So after that you dont need to check if you records in class similar to database records, no case check and so on.
EDIT:
You can add Ids to each of them to store order history in database.

```
Apple = 1,
Meat = 2
```